# Consulta que no repita los datos devueltos

Tags: php, sql, laravel, querybuilder

vengo con un pequeño problemita.

Veran, tengo 3 tablas, *CentroMedico, Medico y Especialidades*

Centro Medico hereda como FK los ID de *CentroMedico y Especialidades*

Lo que quiero hacer es una consulta sql que, en base a un *CentroMedico* especifico, me devuelva las especialidades que existen en ese centro.

Intenté hacer una consulta que de todos los medicos

```
$CentrosMedicos = DB::table('CentrosMedicos')
        ->join('Medicos', 'CentrosMedicos.ID', '=', 'Medicos.centromedico_id')
        ->join('Especialidades', 'Medicos.especialidades_id', '=', 'Especialidades.ID')
        ->select('Especialidades.ID', 
                'Especialidades.especialidad')
        ->get();
```

Esto me devuelve los datos, pero, me devuelve todos las especialidades de cada medico, el problema es que me devuelve una por cada medico, y se que hay una forma de que me devuelva solo 1 de cada especialidad.

Que aunque hayan dos medicos con la especialidad "Cardiologia" solo me devuelva 1, y siga buscando otro diferente.

Comment: ¿Por qué metes a los médicos en la consulta si lo que te interesan son las especialidades? ¿Qué estructura tiene la tabla `Especialidades`?

Comment: Porque los Centros Medicos tienen muchos Medicos y cada Medico tiene su especialidad. Como los Medicos tienen la especialidad, por eso lo uso.

Answer (score 0):

Bien, ya lo resolvi, me costó un poco. La solucion fue sencilla, habia olvidado que existe la funcion `Distinct()` en laravel.

```
$Especialidades = DB::table('CentrosMedicos')
        ->join('Medicos', 'CentrosMedicos.ID', '=', 'Medicos.centromedico_id')
        ->join('especialidades', 'Medicos.especialidad_id', '=', 'Especialidades.ID')
        ->select('Especialidades.ID', 
                'Especialidades.especialidad')
        ->where('CentrosMedicos.ID', '=',$CentroMedico)
        ->distinct('Especialidades.especialidad')
        ->get();
```